# How to extract attributes like in_degree and out_degree of a node from a pyvis graph?

Tags: python, graph, pyvis

I have managed to create a graph using pos tagging in pyvis. But unable to find methods to extract in_degree and out_degree similar to networkx.

Converting pyvis graph to networkx seems to be a solution. Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The pyvis package is used to **visualize** graphs. Instead, NetworkX is a package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of graphs. Their goals are completely different. It wouldn't make any sense to have such functions in a tools meant for visualization only.

What you can do is using NetworkX to build the graph (and manipulate it) and then convert it into the pyvis format to visualize it. You can find an example in the official docs [here](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#networkx-integration).